# How to loop the code when user entered wrong input

Tags: java

```
do {
    id = "";
    quantity = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter id : ");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
        if ((id.toUpperCase()).equals(food[i].getMenuID())) {
            correctInput = true;
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter quantity : ");
                quantity = sc.nextInt();
                if (quantity < 1)
                System.out.println("\nInvalid quantity! Please enter again\n");
        else {
                total = quantity * food[i].getPrice();
                System.out.print(total);
        }
            } while (quantity < 1);
                }
        else if (!((id.toUpperCase()).equals(food[i].getMenuID())))
            System.out.println("\nInvalid ID! Please enter again!\n");
        }
} while (correctInput = false);
```

I want to loop from **"Enter id"** if user entered a wrong **ID**, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried using `do while` loop by setting `boolean` to false when wrong input but it is not working.

How can I achieve that with this code?

I am using JCreator.

Comment: Is the code the one you tried? If not, can you post the do while solution you wrote with boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your correctInput variable is false before your do while code
Also it is `correctInput == false` 
and not `correctInput = false`

Comment: Or just: `while (!correctInput);` which helps eliminate mistakes like this.